# How to fix "is not willing to disclose that one exists" error in run record of jemeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm recording a scenario in `JMeter`. After adding "CSV data set config" or "Regular Expression Extractor", I get this error in the response: **"The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."**

so my scenario does not work.

What should i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the [error source](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/TOMCAT_9_0_0/java/org/apache/catalina/valves/LocalStrings.properties#L74) - it is normal basic [HTTP 404 (Not Found)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) status.

It means that your request URL is pointing to the content which does not exist.

Inspect failing request details using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and double check the URLs - most probably there are references to not existing content.

In case if main requests are fine one of [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) calls might fail, in order to turn off the checks for embedded resources integrity you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
```

However assuming everything is fine with your JMeter script HTTP 404 errors indicate a [SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test) issue which needs to be reported and fixed.